# From a Java EE course test: JPA mapping with annotations mixed with XML. Which has higher priority?

Tags: java, xml, jpa, annotations

On our Java EE course test we had a question, which I am not sure how to answer:

In JPA, if we map with annotations AND XML, which has a higher priority?

- Annotations
- XML
- Depends on configuration
- Depends on the particular implementation of the ORM tool being used.
- None, ORM tool will throw an exception, because XML and annotations must not be combined.

From what I see in [Mixing JPA annotations and XML configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838898/1920149) it is probably possible (even though not advisable), but this one is focused on hibernate, so it does not cover the possible answer, that it depends on the ORM tool implementing JPA being used.

Could you provide some insight to this (with sources, if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML overrides annotations for JPA.  The overriding is at the field/property level.

Section 12.1.2 XML Overriding Rules of the JPA 2.0 ([JSR-317](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317)) specification:

- https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html

Comment: Could you please provide us with some source? It would be very helpful to see it in the specification somewhere, or some other source.

Comment: @Ev0oD - Refer to section 12.1.2 of the JPA 2.0 specification.  I have updated my answer to contain links to this information.